# No sound after login - Kali 2016.2

Tags: kali-linux, audio

I juste made a clean install of the last Kali (not the light one) on my TP300
Full disk and encrypted

Then I updated everything and added Linux headers (I'm not a pro at all with Linux), installed my WiFi driver... and then noticed that I have no sound card in my settings, no sound icon in the control panel, and... no sound ! My sound keys don't work.

I never had this problem with older versions..

I tried a lot of command found on the net but nothing, **I think my pc detect the sound card because I think I saw it several times using commands to display cards etc.. And before login, I can play with the volume, I hear the sound, I see the sound icon, and the key works, but after login.. nothing !**

Do someone have an idea to fix this ?

Comment: I get all back when I enter the "pulseaudio" command, but I need to do it each time I boot, trying to find a fix... why so many problems with linux lol....

Comment: the link here worked for me https://bugs.kali.org/view.php?id=3529 . worth checking out

Comment: Audio is working for all other users but not for root

Answer (score 11):

To fix the problem, type this in the terminal;

```
systemctl --user enable pulseaudio
```

This changes a configuration file to enable `pulseaudio` starting on boot.

Reference: https://bugs.kali.org/view.php?id=3128

Answer (score 5):

To fix the problem;

1. Open Terminal (Ctrl + Alt + T)
2. Now type `sudo gedit /etc/pulse/daemon.conf`
3. Scroll down to find `;daemonize = no`
4. Remove the `;` (as mentioned by @not2qubit)
5. Replace `daemonize = no` with `daemonize = yes`

That should fix it!

Comment: Attention: In that file all the lines are commented out with a `;`, so remove that in front first.

Answer (score 5):

If you are using Kali under a VM, such as VirtualBox, then don't try to change anything by installing another sound processor! First try to change the VM sound card settings. For example, using a Windows host with Kali guest, latest update. You will find that `Intel HD Audio` is not supported in Kali (out-of-the-box). So make sure you have the following VM settings:

```
Host Driver:   Windows DirecSound
Controller:    ICH AC97
```

If there is still no sound on startup, run the following:

```
systemctl --user enable pulseaudio && systemctl --user start pulseaudio
```

Check success with:

```
systemctl --user status pulseaudio
```

If still no success, you may need to reboot.

Whatever, you do, don't randomly try to `apt-get purge <*pulseaudio>` because you may inadvertently remove some Kali features.

Comment: An anonymous user tried to add: 

"Or if you are getting condition failed message with `ConditionUser =!root was not met`. Then run following command `nano /usr/lib/systemd/user/pulseaudio.service` and change `ConditionUser = !root` into `ConditionUser = root`, it worked for me."

Comment: If you are still having problems with *nix sound, please see my [post at RPi SE](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/80075/17798) for an in-depth how-to on using sound on *nix based distros.

Answer (score -1):

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JPTzVcBYVE8

Run `lspci` in a terminal to get your audio device name. Then run `sudo apt-get install libasound2 alsa-utils alsa-oss`. After installing, open `alsamixer`. If any of the channels are muted it will say `MM`; navigate to those channels and press <kbd>m</kbd> to unmute.

Comment: http://image.prntscr.com/image/622f3ae942f946eeb1d2f84a7e9a3aa3.png
Thanks but it don't work, still the same problem

Comment: If `alsa` is not installed by default, then this is a bad suggestion.

Answer (score -1):

In a terminal run `pulseaudio -D`. That would most likely fix your issue.

Pulseaudio wouldn't work with root!
To run it at startup, you need to create a new user and login with those user credentials.

Comment: You should correct this. Pulseaudio can run as root